# AS3 Greensock Chugs in Browser

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, gsap

I'm building an ad in Flash that has a lot of looping MCs playing at once.  When I run a greensock command, it runs fine in Flash, but in the browser it only plays the last frame of the tween.  Without a lot of trial and error, is there a way to know what are the first things I should try to improve performance?

Comment: Helps to see the code.

Comment: There isn't much code.  It's mostly 4 MCs on infinite loop, and when the user interacts it's supposed to do :
TweenLite.to(carousel.mc, 1, {alpha:0, rotationY: 120, onComplete:playVideo});
 TweenLite.to(vidBox, 1, {alpha:1, rotationY: 0});

Comment: I should also mention that the two objects are are being tweened are relatively small.  300x300.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd use a profiler to try and see A good tool that you could use to try and see where the problem is [Adobe Scout](http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/scout/). It will help you identify any bottlenecks or where in the code you may have a problem.

Certain IDEs feature profilers as well including [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) (free) and [Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder.html) ($$$).